# Java based simple rule engine with fallback

Tags: java, implementation, rule-engine, business-rules

I need to implement a simple rules engine with hierarchical fallback support. I have already looked into the DROOLS library but I am not sure if it supports my use case.

The use case is rather simple which makes me thinking whether I need a rules engine at all? Nevertheless, here is the use case -

I have a modal with bunch of fields

```
Public Class Entity {
    public int val0;
    public int val1;
    public int val2;
    public int val3;
    .....
}
```

Now, I want to create rules against these fields as follow

```
RULE1 --- IF val0 == 1 && val1 == 1 && val2 == 1 && val3 == 1 --- (1,1,1,1) THEN DO this
RULE2 --- IF val0 == 1 && val1 == 1 && val2 == 1 && val3 == 2, --- (1,1,1,2) THEN DO this
RULE3 --- IF val0 == 1 && val1 == 1 && val2 == 1 && val3 == *, --- (1,1,1,*) THEN DO this
RULE4 --- IF val0 == 1 && val1 == 1 && val2 == * && val3 == *, --- (1,1,*,*) THEN DO this
```

The problem is with `RULE3` and `RULE4` where val2 and val3 can match any value.

e.g.

```
val0=1, val1=1, val2=1, val3=1 -- should execute RULE1 - specific match
val0=1, val1=1, val2=1, val3=3 -- should execute RULE3 - generic match as there's no specific match for val3
val0=1, val1=1, val2=10, val3=5 -- should execute RULE4 - generic match as there's no specific match for val2 and val3
```

So depending on the query, either I will find the matching rule or I will have to fallback to the more generic rules. Is there any existing rules engine library that provides this functionality or rather do I even need a rules engine library to implement this functionality?

Comment: A full rules engine seems overkill for something that only has a few variants, but it depends on the full context of what you're doing and what you may need to do later.

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought you might want to consider using bitwise logic, but with some of the fields taking non-binary values this probably doesn't really work for you.

However, the solution needn't be that complicated.  Just create a class that acts as a matcher for the values of `Entity` and use a chain of if-else statements to find the match.

```
class EntityMatcher {

    private Integer val0, val1, val2, val3;

    /** Constructor used to match all the parameters */
    EntityMatcher(int val0, int val1, int val2, int val3) {
        // set fields 0-3
    }

    /** Constructor used when you don't care about val2 & val3 */
    EntityMatcher(int val0, int val1) {
        // set fields 0 & 1, leaving val2 and val3 as null
    }

    boolean matches(Entity toMatchAgainst) {
        return (this.val0 == null || this.val0 == toMatchAgainst.val0)
            && (this.val1 == null || this.val1 == toMatchAgainst.val1)
            ...
            && (this.valN == null || this.valN == toMatchAgainst.valN);
    }

}
```

Then your rules engine could look something like this:

```
if (new EntityMatcher(1, 1, 1, 1).matches(entity))
    // Rule 1
else if (new EntityMatcher(1, 1, 1, 2).matches(entity))
    // Rule 2
...
else if (new EntityMatcher(1, 1).matches(entity))
    // Rule 4
...
else
   // no match
```

This is essentially the same idea as [case classes in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html).